# Remote Audio not connecting: iOS, PJSIP 2.6, CallKit, PJSUA2

Tags: ios, iphone, pjsip, avaudiosession, callkit

I am updating an existing iOS VOIP application to use CallKit with PJSIP 2.6 and PJSUA2.

After some effort, the CallKit implementation seems to be working as expected. Incoming calls can be accepted or declined, and if accepted, will be connected and controlled with an in-app active call view controller.

The audio, however, does not appear to be properly connected at the pjsip end. There is no audio coming in from, or going out to the remote caller. The microphone audio appears to be routed back to the iPhone speaker.

The SIP audio ports should be connecting in callback function onCallMediaState:

virtual void onCallMediaState(OnCallMediaStateParam &prm) {

```
    CallInfo ci = getInfo();
    AudioMedia* audio_media = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < ci.media.size(); i++) {
        if (ci.media[i].type==PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO && ( ci.media[i].status == PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE ||
            ci.media[i].status ==PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_REMOTE_HOLD)) {
            try {
                audio_media = static_cast<AudioMedia*>(getMedia(i));
                if(audio_media != 0)
                {    
                    Endpoint::instance().audDevManager().getCaptureDevMedia().startTransmit(*audio_media);
                    audio_media->startTransmit(Endpoint::instance().audDevManager().getPlaybackDevMedia());
                }
            } catch (std::exception ex) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As described in Ticket#1941 at:
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1941:

1. I set the audio devices using:

   ep->audDevManager().setNullDev();

immediately after the initialization of the Endpoint class (`ep->libInit(epConfig);`), and then:

2. I attempt to set the devices using pjsua_set_snd_dev() in CXProvider’s didActivate function, like this:

-(void) setSipSoundDevices {

```
    pj_status_t status;
    int captDev, playDev;
    pjsua_get_snd_dev(&captDev, &playDev);
    Endpoint::instance().audDevManager().setPlaybackDev(playDev);
    Endpoint::instance().audDevManager().setCaptureDev(captDev);
}
```

pjsua_get_snd_dev(&captDev, &playDev) returns -99, -99 and the audio does not connect.

My question is this. How can I properly hook up the remote audio sources or ports, on an incoming call using PJSIP 2.6 and CallKit?

Might 2.5.5 work better in this regard?

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Did you found solution for this problem. I also now strucking in the same problem. After attending the incoming call,no audio produced at both end.

Comment: I am having much better success connecting the audio for both incoming and outgoing calls. No easy answer as to how, but I did a few things that helped by and by. 1) I built and rebuilt the PJSIP 2.6 libraries. PJSUA should not be handling the AudioSession at all (ala PJSIP and CallKit docs). This, however, introduced audio related crashes and failures in the CallKit example code. 2) I installed the 'pjsip' pod and substituted some of the audio related libraries (webrtc comes to mind) for the ones I had built myself. 3) I rearranged a lot of the CallKit code until the audio started connecting.

Comment: I am still facing the issue of 1) incoming call audio not connecting the first time after app start, while outgoing calls connect fine. 2) Outgoing calls not disconnecting without the 'Call Failed' screen, and 3) Audio not reconnecting after an interrupting carrier call is dismissed after 'Hold and Accept'.

Comment: how to start audio when user clicks answer button on callkit screen. Could you please explain this. In my case callkit is working as a another app.. while attending the call my app is gone to background. Then user clicks on answer button, the audio is not working bcoz my app is gone to background.

Comment: In my case outgoing call is working perfectly, bcoz im using separate view controller. I just added permission for microphone in info.plist file. For hold and unhold there is method in pjsip. Please verify it and correct it.

Answer (score 2):

By and by I got the incoming call audio working properly. The crux of the matter was that even though the documentation from both Apple and SIP say that the audio has to be handled on the iOS end, you still have to set the SIP audio devices in the SIP layer in the provider delegate 'didActivate' and 'didDeactivate' functions. Because I use the PJSUA C++ layer, I had to drill down through the objc-c++ bridging layer to provide this functionality. ie.

```
-(void) activateSipSoundDevices {
    pj_status_t status = pjsua_set_snd_dev(0, 0);
}

-(void) deactivateSipSoundDevices {
    pj_status_t status = pjsua_set_null_snd_dev();
}
```

When initializing the SIP Account, be sure to set the null sound devices like:

```
ep->audDevManager().setNullDev();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Can you please tell me how did you get the incoming calls when app is killed. Do app receives any singnal (not push) and we can capture that in callkit incomming delegate method?

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to catch incoming call while app is terminated is push.